# How to integrate $\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx$$
I've been attempting this problem for days and I've made very little progress. I understand that I should substitute $x=\tan(x)$ and $dx=\sec^2(x)dx$ but beyond that I am very much lost.

Comment: You can look up the reduction formula for $\sec(x)$, which might help you complete this. http://calc101.com/deriving_reduction_4.html

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen nevermind, I thought you wrote just $\sin$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So really you are interested in,

$$I=\int \sec^3(x) dx$$

Integration by parts , integrating $\sec^2 x$ and differentiating $\sec x$, gives:

$$=\sec x \tan x- \int \sec x \tan^2 x$$

$$=\sec x \tan x-\int \sec x (\sec x^2-1)$$

$$=\sec x \tan x-I+\ln (\sec x +\tan x)+C_1$$

So that

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\sec x \tan x+\frac{1}{2}\ln (\sec x+\tan x)+C$$

Now set up a triangle to figure out what $\sec \theta, \tan \theta$ are.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense than my approach

Comment: If you say so. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 7):

Making the substitution $x=\sinh u$ we have $$\int \sqrt{x^2+1} \; \mathrm{d}x=\int \cosh^2 u \;\mathrm{d}u=\int \frac{\cosh 2u+1}{2} \; \mathrm{d}u=\frac{\sinh 2u}{4}+\frac{u}{2}=\frac{\sinh u \cosh u}{2}+\frac{u}{2}$$
Using the [hyperbolic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) and their [sum of arguements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Sums_of_arguments). As we know $$\sinh u=x, \cosh u=\sqrt{x^2+1}, u=\sinh^{-1} x$$ the answer is $$\frac{1}{2} \left(x \sqrt{x^2+1}+\sinh^{-1} x\right)$$
Where $\sinh^{-1} x$ denotes the inverse hyperbolic sine function.

Comment: Is there any particular reason I should use hyperbolic functions instead of normal trig functions?

Comment: @Nathan Does that address your question?

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: @S.C.B. The inverse hyperbolic trig functions can be written in terms of logs. It's not pretty, but the answer can be completely written out in closed form.

Answer (score 2):

If we stick with your idea, we have
$$
\int \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\,dx =
\int \sqrt{\tan^2\theta + 1}\, \sec^2\theta \,d\theta = \\
\int\sec^3\theta\,d \theta
$$
For this integral, one would use the formula
$$
\int\sec^3\theta\,d \theta = \int (1 + \tan^2 \theta) \sec \theta\,d \theta  =\\
\int \sec \theta \,d \theta  + \int \tan \theta (\tan \theta \sec \theta) \,d\theta
$$
The first integral has a formula you can look up, using the trick
$$
\int \sec \theta \,d \theta = 
\int \frac{\sec \theta \tan \theta + \sec^2 \theta}{\sec \theta + \tan \theta} \,d \theta
$$
or using the half-angle substitution. The second can be done by parts, which gets you
$$
\int \tan \theta (\tan \theta \sec \theta) \,d\theta = 
\tan \theta \sec \theta - \int \sec^3 \theta \, d\theta
$$
which brings you to an equation on $\int \sec^3 \theta \, d\theta$ that can be solved.

Comment: See Ahmed's version for a cleaner approach

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

$$\int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx = \int\frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx = \int x\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx + \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\,dx = x\sqrt{x^2+1} - \int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx\,+ \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}) \implies \int\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\big(x\sqrt{x^2+1}+\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\big) + C $$