# Draw and find the Length of $x = t + 4, y = t^2 + 1$

Tags: integration, arc-length

I want a confirmation for this exercise.

My try:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZwW.png)

Thanks.

Comment: It is dx (I am not good at painting)

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula $$l=\int_{t_0}^{t}\sqrt{\dot{x^2}+\dot {y^2}}dt=\int_{0}^t\sqrt{1+4t^2}dt$$
The indefinite integral has the form $$\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 t^2+1} t+\frac{1}{4} \sinh ^{-1}(2
   t)$$

Answer (score 0):

You set up the definite integral correctly:
$$L=\int_4^6 \sqrt{1+y'^2}dx=\int_4^6 \sqrt{1+(2x-8)^2}dx$$
However, you are adding $2(2x-8)^2$ without reason.

Instead, denote: $2x-8=t$ to get:
$$L=\int_0^4\sqrt{1+t^2}\cdot \frac12dt,$$
which you can evaluate by changing $t=\tan y$ or $t=\sinh y$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125242/how-to-integrate-int-sqrtx21dx). Answer must be approximately $4.64678$ as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E4%5Csqrt%7B1%2Bt%5E2%7D%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac12dt).