# Help in finding the integrate of a quadratic.

Tags: calculus

$$\int_0^{0.904463} \sqrt{1+(2.343548x-0.812495)^2 }dx$$
I have tried this question several times but can't answer it. I know it involves trig functions a u-subsitution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: This is a fairly standard integral cal question, except for the 'ridiculous' numbers. What is the context? do you need this for a cal course, or do you need the answer for use elsewhere?

Comment: No, It's for a paper I'm writing. Is it possible you show me how it's done.

Comment: For a paper you can compute it with an online calculator: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate++sqrt%281%2B%282.343548x-0.812495%29%5E2+%29+from+0+to+0.904463

Comment: @user has suggested wolfram alpha. For the general method to calculate the integral (after making a substitution to get rid of the $ ax -b$, $a$ and $b$ being your specific numbers ), see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125242/how-to-integrate-int-sqrtx21dx Does this help?

Comment: I tried using wolfram but i need to pay money for the steps. Would anyone be kind enough to solve it ?@user @peter a g

Comment: Why should you pay money? I assume for the paper you need only the number, and it is $\approx1.07175$. If you need a higher precision just tell me which one.

Comment: @user I need to explain the steps on my  paper

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{1+(ax-b)^2}dx&\stackrel{ax-b\mapsto\sinh t}=\frac1a\int\cosh t\; d\sinh t= \frac1a\int\cosh^2 t\; dt\\
&=\frac1{2a}\int(1+\cosh 2t)\; d t= \frac1{2a}\left(t+\frac12\sinh2t\right)\\
&=\frac{t+\sinh t\cosh t}{2a}\\
&=\frac{\sinh^{-1}(ax-b)+(ax-b)\sqrt{1+(ax-b)^2}}{2a}.
\end{align}$$
The substitution of the numbers is left to you.

Comment: But I have a definite integral. Would this still work.

Comment: @OmarBashady Of course. Do you know how to compute definite integral from the known antiderivative?

Comment: No. Can you explain. Sorry.

Comment: @OmarBashady https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Newton-Leibniz_formula. What is your paper about?

Comment: I dont thinks this works. II understand how to find the definite integral from the known antiderivative but its not working. can you show me it works please.

Comment: It works. Show me where you stuck. And you forgot to answer the question about the topic of your paper.

Comment: When I plug in 0.904463(upper limit) as x it does not give me 1.071750442 which is the answer. My lower limit is 0.

Comment: Let me know what numbers you have obtained by plugging in $0$ and $0.904463$.

Comment: 0.904463=0.839199

Comment: 0= 0.2579751783

Comment: And I obtain $0.690007$ and $-0.381744$. So please look for an error in your computation...

Comment: Thanks alot. You literally saved my life.

Comment: One more question. Why did you equate ax-b=sinh t. Why not equate ax-b to some something else

Comment: @OmarBashady This question I will answer after you tell us what is the topic of your paper.

Comment: Oh of course I forgot to answer that. It's about measuring the crash frequency of a curved road. I performed quadratic regression to get a function for the data points I collected on the road. I then need to measure the arc length of a specfic part of the quadratic to find the lentgh of the road.

Comment: Very interesting. The story with $\sinh $ is just experience. As soon as one encounters the expression $\sqrt {1\pm x^2} $ the first substitution to try is depending on the sign  $\sin x $ or $\sinh x $.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer for the general formula

$$\int\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}\,dx$$

(in your case, you can pull the coefficient of $x$ out of the square root; mind the $2p$).

We can write

$$x^2+2px+q=(x+p)^2+q-p^2=(x+p)^2\pm d^2.$$

We observe that

$$\left(x\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}\right)'=\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}+\frac{x^2+px}{\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}}
\\=2\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}-\frac{px+q}{\sqrt{x^2+2px+2q}}$$

and

$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}\right)'=\frac{x+p}{\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}}$$

and

$$\left(\text{arsinh}\frac{x+p}d\right)'=\frac1{d\sqrt{(x+p)^2+d^2}}$$ or $$\left(\text{arcosh}\frac{x+p}d\right)'=\frac1{d\sqrt{(x+p)^2-d^2}}.$$

Hence the antiderivative is of the form

$$(ax+b)\sqrt{x^2+2px+q}+c\text{ arsinh/arcosh}\frac{x+p}d$$

where $a,b,c$ can be obtained by the method of indeterminate coefficients.

Comment: But I have a definite integral. Would this still work.

Comment: @OmarBashady: hem, how do you compute definite integrals ?