Integration of $\int\frac{3z^3-8z+5}{\sqrt{z^2-4z-7}}\,dz$
This is going to be a long one.

Evaluate the integral
$\int\cfrac{3z^3-8z+5}{\sqrt{z^2-4z-7}}dz$.

With some help from the internet I could do this much:
$u=z-2;\ u=\sqrt{11}\sec v$
This transforms the original integral to
\begin{align}
\int&\frac{3(u+2)^3-8(u+2)+5}{\sqrt{u^2-11}}\,du \\
&= \int{\cfrac{3(\sqrt{11}\sec v+2)^3-8(\sqrt{11}\sec v)-11}{\sqrt{11\sec^2v-11}}\times \sqrt{11}\sec v \tan v }\,dv \\
&= \int3\sec v(\sqrt{11}\sec v+2)^3 dv-\int 8\sqrt{11}\sec^2v \,dv-\int 11\sec v \,dv
\end{align}
Now to evaluate the three integrals separately:
The second part is: $-8\sqrt{11}\tan v$
The third part is: $11\ln|{\sec v+\tan v}|$
The first part causes all the problems:
$$3\int \sec v(\sqrt{11}\sec v+2)^3\ dv = \frac{3}{\sqrt{11}}\int (\sec v(\sqrt{11}\sec v+2)^4-2(\sqrt{11}\sec v+2)^3) \,dv$$
And I couldn't understand what the solution did to the rest. It involved binomial expansion then integration of different terms but yeah I could neither integrate those nor substitute propley
So

What to do next?
Is there a faster way to evaluate this mess?
Is there a faster way to solve this question(multiple correct)?



I found this post.

I've taken the liberty of doing some quick formatting to improve readability. Please typeset the question in the image.

How about $$\sqrt{z^2-4z-7}\left(z^2+5z+36\right)+112\log\left(\frac{z-2+\sqrt{z^2-4z-7}}{\sqrt{11}}\right)$$

$3z^3-8z+5=\frac32(z^2-4z-7)(2z-4)+18(z^2-4z-7)+\frac{61}2(2z-4)+211$

Is the question about evaluating the integral or solving the multiple-choice question in screenshot? If it is the latter, then I would try differentiating both sides and comparing coefficient of $z$, $z^2$ and $z^3$ to see which option is correct.

I notice answer by @TravisWillse (in point $3$) employs similar technique I mentioned above


The difficult part of the first integral is evaluating
$$\int \sec^3 v \,dv .$$
The standard method is tricky: Apply integration by parts, use a trigonometric identity, apply parts again, then rearrange; see e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2125258/155629 and the dedicated Wikipedia rticle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed.

Hint Instead, apply to the given integral a variant of Euler's First Substitution, $$\sqrt{z^2 - 4 z - 7} = (z - 2) + t ,$$
to rationalize the integral (in fact, rewrite it as a sum of powers):
$$\frac18 \int \left(3 t^2 - 36 t + 211 - \frac{896}t + \frac{2321}{t^2} - \frac{4356}{t^3} + \frac{3993}{t^4}\right) \,dt .$$

Probably the fastest way to proceed is just to the differentiate the given antiderivative, which is somewhat tedious but still faster than direct integration,
giving
\begin{multline}
\frac{d}{dz}\left[(z^2 + a z + 36) \sqrt{z^2 - 4 z - 7} + b \log \left\vert z - 2 + \sqrt{z^2 - 4 z - 7}\right\vert + C\right] \\
= \frac{3 z^3 + (2 a - 10) z^2 + (-6 a + 22) z + (-7 a + b - 72)}{\sqrt{z^2 - 4 z - 7}},
\end{multline}
and compare coefficients of the numerator with the integrand.



Is it advisable to not attempt such questions should they ever come in a test?( assuming at most 5 minutes per question)

Differentiating is fast enough here. I wouldn't attempt another method in a timed setting like that, though---not only is direct integration time-consuming, (as Quanto's answer shows) there are many equivalent forms of the antiderivative, and depending on your method you might have to then spend time massaging your antiderivative into the particular form in the question statement.

By the affine change of variables we get the integral of the form
$$ \int {P(u)\over \sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du$$ where $P(u)$ is a third degree polynomial. Then $P(u)$ can be represented as $$P(u)=au(u^2-1)+bu +c(u^2-1)+d$$ We obtain four integrals $$\int u\sqrt{u^2-1}\,du={1\over 3}(u^2-1)^{3/2},\ \int{u\over \sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du=\sqrt{u^2-1},\\\int \sqrt{u^2-1}\,du, \ \ \int{1\over \sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du$$ The last one is well known $\ln(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}).$ The third one can be represented in terms of the last one applying the  integration by parts, namely
$$ \int \sqrt{u^2-1}\,du=u\sqrt{u^2-1}-\int {u^2\over \sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du \\
=u\sqrt{u^2-1}-\int {1+(u^2-1)\over \sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du \\
=u\sqrt{u^2-1}-\int {1\over \sqrt{u^2-1}}\,du-\int\sqrt{u^2-1}\,du$$

Introduce the shorthand $g(z)=z^2-4z-7$. Then, $g’(z)=2z-4$,
$$\left[ g’(x) \sqrt{g(z)}\right]’=\frac{4g(z)+22}{\sqrt{g(z)}}
$$
and
\begin{align}
&\int\cfrac{3z^3-8z+5}{\sqrt{z^2-4z-7}}dz\\
=& \int \frac{[\frac32g(z)+\frac{61}2]g’(z)+18g(z)+211}{\sqrt{g(z)}}\ dz\\
=&\int\bigg(\frac{3}2 \sqrt{g(z)} +\frac{61 }{2 \sqrt{g(z)}}\bigg) g’(z) +\frac92 \left[ g’(x) \sqrt{g(z)}\right]’+\frac{112}{\sqrt{g(z)}}\ dz\\
=&\ \sqrt{g(z)^3}+61 \sqrt{g(z)}+ +\frac92 g’(x) \sqrt{g(z)}+112 \coth^{-1}\frac{g’(z)}{2\sqrt{g(z)}}
\end{align}
